# Dictionary pattern matching error

Tags: python, regex

I have this dictionary:

```
mydict = {'greet': ['Hello123','hi45'],
          'say': 'thankyou789',
          'slang': ['Bmyguest','Bmyfriend']}
```

I want to fetch the keys based on partially matched user inputs, e.g.:

If the user enters `'Brightback'`, I should return `'slang'` since only `'slang'` contains entries starting with `'B'`. If the user enters `'Hello'` or `'hi'`, I should return `'greet'`.

```
input="Brightback"
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    if input.startswith(value):
        print key
```

this gives out the error:

> TypeError: startswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not list

Comment: `value` is a list so you need to iterate over it too

Comment: And if you use startswith(value), it will not return true just because both words start with B. What input.startswith(value) does is it check if `input` starts with `value`. So if you have `Bandit` as input and `Bmyguest` as value it returns false. It would return true if input was `BmyguestBandit` because now input indeed startswith(value).

Comment: @Philipp That's the next question (c:

Answer (score 1):

If `value` is a list you need to iterate over it.

Below I put the value in a list if it's a string, otherwise I leave it as it is.

I've changed the name to `values` as it is more than one:

```
input="Brightback"
for key, values in mydict.iteritems():
    values = [values] if type(values) is str else values
    for value in values:
        if input.startswith(value):
            print key
            break
```

Also, to save printing the same key twice, I break out of the `value in values` loop to try the next key.

I like to simplify code, and your loop is really a search for any value matching the start of the word. Python has a builtin function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
input="Brightback"
for key, values in mydict.iteritems():
    values = [values] if type(values) is str else values
    if any(input.startswith(value) for value in values):
        print key
```

Comment: `value` is not always a list in the case of `'say':'thankyou789'` for example.

Comment: @Lucho Fixed to put string into list

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement one more check; if value is a `list` or not; if `list` then if any value starts with that value or not..

```
In [1]: mydict={'greet':['Hello123','hi45'],'say':'thankyou789','slang':['Bmyguest','Bmyfriend']}

In [2]: myinput="Brightback"

In [3]: for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
   ...:     if isinstance(value, list):
   ...:         if any(x.startswith(myinput) for x in value):
   ...:             print key
   ...:     elif value.startswith(myinput):
   ...:         print key
   ...:         

In [4]: myinput="hi"

In [5]: for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
   ...:     if isinstance(value, list):
   ...:         if any(x.startswith(myinput) for x in value):
   ...:             print key
   ...:     elif value.startswith(myinput):
   ...:         print key
   ...:         
greet

In [6]: myinput="thank"

In [7]: for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
   ...:     if isinstance(value, list):
   ...:         if any(x.startswith(myinput) for x in value):
   ...:             print key
   ...:     elif value.startswith(myinput):
   ...:         print key
   ...:         
say

In [8]:
```